# Show that $T$ is independent of $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

Define $$T: C_{0}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}$$ by $$T(\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}+\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$$

I need to show that $T$ is independent of $\epsilon$.

For this I take $\epsilon $ and $\delta$ different from each other and both $\gt 0$ . Without loss of generality I assume that $\epsilon \gt \delta$. Then I consider the difference $$|\int_{-\infty}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}+\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}-\int_{-\infty}^{\delta}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}-\int_{-\delta}^{\delta}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}-\int_{\delta}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}|$$
$$=|\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\delta}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}+\int_{-\epsilon}^{-\delta}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}+\int_{\delta}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}+\int_{\delta}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}|$$

Then by taking the maximum of upper bounds of $\phi$ and $\phi'$ as $M$, I came to $2M((\epsilon-\delta)+\log(\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}))$.
This is no good for me as I cannot make it less than an arbitrary $\epsilon_1$.

Then I thought of another way:

I defined

$$T_n(\phi)=\int_{-n}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}+\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}+\int_{\epsilon}^{n}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}$$

Then if I differentiate $T_n(\phi)$ with respect to $\epsilon$, it is easy to see that the result will come out to be $0$. Since this is true for all $n$ , I think it can be concluded from here for the general case as well.

Is this line of thinking correct??

Is there anyother way??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Differentiate $T(ϕ,ɛ)$ wrt. $ɛ$. The result is 0 so $T(ϕ,ɛ)$ does not depend on $ɛ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\phi$ has compact support, there is an $N$ such that $n\ge N\implies T_n=T$. This makes your last argument correct.

Another aay too do it is to observe that if the support of $ºphi$ is contained in $[_N,N]$, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx&=\int_{-N}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{N}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx\\
\int_{-N}^{-\epsilon}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\,dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{N}\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\,dx.
\end{align}$$